Unable to Connect to AWS RDS (postgresql) from GitHub Codespaces Using IPv4
I am currently using GitHub Codespaces for my development environment. My setup involves an IPv6 VPC connected to an AWS RDS instance.
When I attempt to connect to the RDS instance using the following command:
psql postgresql://root:password@db:5432/db

(I am using the correct credentials in the actual command)
I encounter connectivity issues and the connection fails.
Due to the cost implications of using IPv4, I am trying to switch to IPv6. However, it appears that GitHub Codespaces does not provide IPv6 support.
I have configured both inbound and outbound rules in my VPC security group. When I execute the following command to modify the security group rules:
aws ec2 modify-security-group-rules \
--group-id $DB_SG_ID \
--security-group-rules "SecurityGroupRuleId=$DB_SG_RULE_ID,SecurityGroupRule={Description=GITHUB,IpProtocol=tcp,FromPort=5432,ToPort=5432,CidrIpv4=$(curl ifconfig.me)/32}"

The update is reflected in the VPC security group settings. However, despite these settings, I am unable to connect to the AWS RDS instance using the psql command.
In contrast, when using an IPv4 VPC connected to the AWS RDS instance, the connection is established successfully without any issues.
Could someone help identify why the connection is failing with the IPv6 VPC configuration and suggest possible solutions or troubleshooting steps?

I'm a little confused. Are you trying to get IPv6 going, or are you just trying to get IPv4 working with GitHub Codespaces? Or are you trying to connect to it from your own IP address (hence using ipconfig.me)?
